# Simple Prolog program: "Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated" error

Tags: prolog, clpfd, instantiation-error

I am writing a Prolog predicate that cuts first three elements off a numbered list and prints the result. An example of a numbered list:

```
[e(f,1),e(o,2),e(o,3),e(b,4),e(a,5),e(r,6)].
```

The original predicate for normal list looks like this:

```
strim([H|T],R) :-   
   append(P,R,[H|T]),  
   length(P,3).
```

So, since length predicate works perfectly for numbered lists as well, I only had to write predicate that appends one numbered list to another:

```
compose([],L,[L]).
compose([e(F,C)|T],e(A,_),[e(F,C)|L]) :-
   N is C+1,
   compose(T,e(A,N),L).

napp(X,[],X).
napp(L,[e(X,Y)|T],M):-
   compose(L,e(X,Y),L1),
   napp(L1,T,M).
```

I expected the predicate for numbered list to be a slightly modified version of predicate for normal list, so I wrote this:

```
numstrim([e(X,Y)|T],R) :-
   napp(P,R,[e(X,Y)|T]),
   length(P,3).
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: compose/3: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Could somebody please explain what's causing the error and how to avoid it? I'm new to Prolog.

Comment: `N is C+1` requires that `C` be instantiated since it's trying to evaluate `C+1`.

Comment: @lurker alright! sorry to ask a simple question like this, but how would it look in my code? I read a bit on instantiating variables, but I don't see what I can do in this case specifically...

Comment: Nothing wrong with a simple question. :) But you might end up with more homework. "Instantiated" means it needs a value bound to it. So if `C` has no value, then Prolog cannot evalutate `C+1` and you get an instantiation error. To fix it, you need to examine your logic and ensure that `C` has a value. You call `compose(L, e(X,Y), L1)` and Prolog will eventually attempt the second clause for `compose/3` which matches `L` with `[e(F,C)|T]`, with no value bound to `C`. So `N is C + 1` fails with an instantiation error.

Comment: I meant to say that "'instantiated' means it *has* a value bound to it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiation errors are a common phenomenon in Prolog programs that use **moded** predicates: These are predicates that can only be used in special *circumstances*, requiring for example that some arguments are fully *instantiated* etc.

As a beginner, you are in my view well advised to use **more general predicates** instead, so that you can freely exchange the order of goals and do not have to take procedural limitations into account, at least not so early, and without the ability to freely experiment with your code.

For example, in your case, the following *trivial* change to `compose/3` gives you a predicate that works in all directions:

```
compose([], L, [L]).
compose([e(F,C)|T], e(A,_), [e(F,C)|L]) :-
        N #= C+1,
        compose(T, e(A,N), L).
```

Here, I have simply replaced the *moded* predicate `(is)/2` with the **CLP(FD) constraint** `(#=)/2`, which completeley subsumes the more low-level predicate over integers.

After this small change (depending on your Prolog system, you may have to import a library to use the more general arithmetic predicates), we get:

```
?- numstrim([e(f,1),e(o,2),e(o,3),e(b,4),e(a,5),e(r,6)], Es).
nontermination
```

So, we find out that the instantiation error has actually overshadowed a different problem that can only be understood procedurally, and which has now come to light.

To improve this, I now turn around the two goals of `numstrim/2`:

```
numstrim([e(X,Y)|T], R) :-
        length(P, 3),
        napp(P, R, [e(X,Y)|T]).
```

This is because `length(P, 3)` **always terminates**, and placing a goal that always terminates *first* can at most *improve*, never worsen, the termination properties of a pure and monotonic logic program.

So now we get:

```
?- numstrim([e(f,1),e(o,2),e(o,3),e(b,4),e(a,5),e(r,6)], Es).
Es = [e(b, _1442), e(a, _2678), e(r, _4286)] .
```

That is, at least we get *an answer* now!

However, the predicate still *does not terminate* **universally**, because we get:

```
?- numstrim([e(f,1),e(o,2),e(o,3),e(b,4),e(a,5),e(r,6)], Es), false.
nontermination
```

I leave fixing this as an exercise.